# Regression analyis based on questionaire surveys

Tags: multiple-regression, survey

I want to do an regression analysis based on a questionnaire survey regarding taking risks. I have 80 respondents from the questionnaire.

My dependent variable is a gamble question: where options are such as 1000, 5000 and 10 000 to gamble.

My independent variables are such as gender, education, age and income with different answer options.

I will put up each individual answers on a excel sheet. When I put them up how should I interpret them? Should I example rank the answer option with number? For example Female=1 Male=2 and for education the same bachelor=1, master=2 and Phd=3 and so on to make it easier? or is it possible to just write the answer as it is. indnividual 1 chose male, bachelor, gambled 1000. Individual 2 chose xxxxx

Is it possible to make an multiple regression analysis using this structure? or are there any other structure I can set up the data from the respondents to make and multipple regression analysis?

Comment: How much lines per person will you have in your sheet?

Comment: 1 line for each respondents, where the line consist of Respondent 1, gender, education, work, income, gamble